# Why two of my onClick() buttons crashes app

Tags: java, android

I am teaching myself coding by making an app.

I have a minimal functioning snake game in one project https://github.com/byn3/BynSnake

My goal is to put that working snake app into an onClick() button of my app that I'm making to learn stuff https://github.com/byn3/BryanLeungApp.

**My question is, how do I get the last button (the onClick "Play Snake" to stop crashing the app?**

The blue "Play Snake" button that I have crashes the app when clicked. I copied over the two classes, "SnakeActivity" and "SnakeView" and modified some other stuff. My suspect is that there is something wrong with my call to start activity

```
public void SnakeActivity(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, SnakeActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Or that my AndroidManifest folder is incorrect in making the activity

```
<activity
    android:name=".SnakeActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I've been doing side by side code comparisons in both projects but I finally decided to make an account and ask for help because I have been stuck on this for too long and the answer might probably be something out of my scope of knowledge.

Comment: put logcat here to better help

Comment: We can't tell you how to stop the crash because we don't know what caused it and we can't know that because you have shown us no error message or logs. We can't fix a problem if we don't know what the problem is. "_The blue 'Play Snake' button that I have crashes the app when clicked_" That seems like relevant code to show us then...

Comment: as you said Why two of my onClick() buttons crashes app but where is the code of onclick button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file. SnakeActivity should use AppComat theme. Try using `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` instead of `@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen`

And here is the log:

```
Process: com.example.android.bryanleung, PID: 2832
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.bryanleung/com.example.android.bryanleung.SnakeActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2684)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1496)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6186)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:359)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:328)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:280)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:145)
                                                     at com.example.android.bryanleung.SnakeActivity.onCreate(SnakeActivity.java:37)
                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6684)
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2637)
```

Comment: Can you please explain what _exactly_ is the problem with using `@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen` in this case?

Comment: Sure. Activity is using AppCompatActivity witch prohibits any non-appcompat themes

Comment: YOU GOT IT!! Thanks this is the right answer. I was getting the debug logs as the others requested and found that the problem was exactly this. Followed your instructions, replaced. Now it works fine and as intended. Thank you